# How to show two radio button next to each other in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have my html form like this as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/16/).

If you click `PROCESS` button then it will show you a form which has two radio button. And they all are coming vertically for now, meaning female radio button is coming just below male radio button.

And I am trying to make them in one line - meaning `Male` radio button and then next to male, I need `Female` radio button, everything horizontal. But somehow it's not working for me.

But the same example here in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio) works fine.

I would like to use the same design which I am using currently. Is there anything wrong I am doing here in my above jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `form input, form button#submit {` to `#submit {`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4Nmqk/20/)**

Your `display:block` rule is being applied to all input elements and you don't want to include the radio inputs there.

Comment: Better to remove `display: inline-block;` from the fiddle :)

Comment: @HashemQolami - Doesn't really make a difference in this case.

Comment: Absolutely, just sayin'. As it's redundant in this case.

Comment: @j08691: It works fine but take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/21/) which I modified yours just by adding one textbox. Now everything is coming horizontal.. I would like to have only radio button coming horizontal and other thing should come as vertical. Meaning two radio button horizontal and then textbox at the bottom of that. Is this possible to do.. I should have provided this in the question. Sorry about that..

Comment: Well, since you're changing the example, an easy fix would be to instead use a new rule, `input[type="radio"] {display:inline;
}`. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4Nmqk/23/)

Answer (score 2):

You'd use:

```
form input[type="radio"] {
  display: inline-block;    
}
```

As currently you were displaying it as a block-line element instead (along with the submit), hence why it was appearing below.

<kbd>**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/18/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
 form button#submit 
{
display: inline;
margin: 4px;
 }
```

change the style to above.